# How to Implement Box Function in better way in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

- This function in Matlab presents Box_Function:

  - output = 1 while sample n belongs to the range  (-a, +a).
  - otherwise the output is 0 outside that range.
- So how can I implement this function in Matlab in a better way to shift the plot in case of negative values of time, **without assigning negative values to the array**.

**Thanks in Advance**

```
function B_X = Box_Func(N,K,a)
if(N <= 0)||(K+a > N) 
    warning('Please Enter Valid Positive Integer !');
else 
    B_X = zeros([-N N]); 
    for i = -N : 1 : N 
         if (i >= K-a) && (i <= K+a) 
            B_X(i)=1;
        end
    end
end
end
```

Comment: This is, in essence, the same question as the one about Heaviside. Indices in MATLAB are integers starting at 1. You can’t use negative indices.

Comment: You need to explain how you intend to use this function. Negative indices don’t exist, so this code will never work and you can’t really fix it.  What problem are you trying to solve with this function?

Comment: The brilliant solution is not to use indices below 1. First, `zeros([-N N])` might not result in what you expect (read the [docs for zeros](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html)). Next, the loop variable from `-N : 1 : N` will use negative values and zero as an index. Read the [docs for indexing](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html).

Having read the docs is a prerequisite of getting answers. If you have problem to understand the docs or to implement something according to them, we will be happy to answer.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "I just want my Function to appear on the plotting shifted on X Axis, so it looks like that the center of the Box Function is in the negative area of X axis". Maybe you could draw (by hand in some graphic program) what your results should look like. We definitely need more information on what you want to achieve. Besides this, since you know that negative indexing isn't working, try to modify your code to not use negative (or zero) indexing and show us your attempt and your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, one remark to the lines

```
if(N <= 0)||(K+a > N) % if samples Number wrong, or shifting exceeds limit
    % of Samples Print a warning.
    warning('Please Enter Valid Positive Integer !');
```

I suggest to throw an `error` instead of a `warning` if the input parameters are wrong and will lead to an error anyway. Otherwise you could omit the test and let Matlab throw the respective error.

The next misunderstanding is

```
B_X = zeros([-N N])
```

What do you expect `B_X` to be after this line if, let's say, `N=2`? Test if the result is what you expect by simply entering this command in the command line directly:

```
>> zeros([-2 2])

ans =

  0×2 empty double matrix
```

I guess that's not what you expect. As [the docs](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) state, `zeros(N)` will yield a square matrix with `N` rows and `N` columns; `zeros(M,N)` will yield a matrix with `M` rows and `N` columns. Look:

```
>> zeros(2)

ans =

     0     0
     0     0

>> zeros(2,1)

ans =

     0
     0
```

I do not know what you expect from `zeros([-2 2])`, but I guess that you are looking for one of the following:

```
>> N = 2;
>> zeros(2*N+1,1)

ans =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     0

>> zeros(1,2*N+1)

ans =

     0     0     0     0     0

>> zeros(2*N+1)

ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

My guess is that somehow you expect the function `zeros` to operate on some range of indices you provide. Your misunderstanding might be that you expect `zeros([-2 2])` to provide a vector of zeros into which you can index using `-2:2` (that is, one of `-2,-1,0,+1,+2`). If you assume this, your assumption is wrong.

I guess this from the line

```
for i = -N : 1 : N
```

in your code. Due to this line, I'll first thought that

```
>> B_X = zeros(1, 2*N+1)

B_X =

     0     0     0     0     0
```

is what you expect. However, from the comment

```
% if samples Number wrong, or shifting exceeds limit
```

I guessed that `N` might be just the number of data points in the result. This would mean

```
>> B_X = zeros(1, N)

B_X =

     0     0
```

(which would not make much sense for `N=2`). So, for the next question you ask (or an edit to this question): **Clearly explain the meaning of the function inputs!**

Since later, you set the limits of your x-axes to `[-N N]`, I'll keep my first assumption, thus the number of data points (and therefore the argument to `zeros`) should be `2*N+1`.

The next argument to your function is `K`, you call it *the shift*. `k` only occurs in combination with the third input of the function, `a`. You do not provide any inforamtion about `a`.

From this line I guess that `a` is something that specifies a width:

```
if (i >= K-a) && (i <= K+a)
```

Now, slowly, if one also considers

```
B_X(i)=1;
```

and the usage of the word *box* (and *heaviside*, which is still in the comments), one can get a clue of what you want to do. Together with your comment that you want your function

> to  appear on the plotting shifted on X Axis, so it looks like that the center of the Box Function is in the negative area of X axis

Might this be your goal: *I want to plot a vector from `-N` to `N` (in steps of `1`) with zero values except for the region of `-K±a`, where I want it to be one*?

If this is the case, one attempt would be as follows (it remains to you to put it into a function):

```
>> N=15;
>> K=7;
>> a = 3;
```

Get the x-values:

```
>> x = -N:N;
```

(`-15`, `-14`, ... `14`, `15`). Next, allocate `B_X`:

```
>> B_X = zeros(1, 2*N+1);
```

Last, use logical indexing ([this might help to understand this](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/)) to set the values around `-K±a` to one:

```
>> B_X(x>(-K-a) & x<(-K+a)) = 1;
```

Eventually, plot the result:

```
plot(x,B_X);
```

and adjust the axis limits:

```
>> ax=gca;
>> ax.YLim = [-.2 1.2];
```

Result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation and the Brilliant solution, that was a clear explanation for the problem and the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
function B_X = Box_Func(N,K,a)
%   Box_Func This Function takes Number of Samples N,Count of shift K, and 
%   half of Box width a then it stem Them ,
%   Note it works only for positive shifting
%   that means K should be positive or Zero

if(N <= 0)||(K+a > N) % if samples Number wrong, or shifting exceeds limit
    % of Samples Print a warning.
    warning('Please Enter Valid Positive Integer !');
else % if The inputs are fine , then :
    B_X = zeros([1 2*N+1]);
    x = -N:N;
    B_X(x>=(K-a) & x<=(K+a)) = 1;
    end
%===========================================    
% Plotting the Results
%=========================================== 
    figure('Name','Box Function','NumberTitle','off');
    stem(x,B_X)
    hold on
    xlabel('Samples')
    ylabel('Box Shifeted Function')
    xlim([-N N]) ;
    ylim([-1 2]);
    grid on
    hold off
end
```